# Выборка по определенному значению из MySQL в Java JDBC

Tags: java

Прошу помочь разобраться:
Я сделал выборку из БД MySQL. Сейчас в БД таблицы Wordpress, собственно я сделал выборку постов таким вот образом:

```
String sql = "SELECT post_date, post_title, guid FROM wp_posts";
```

Все работает корректно. Но я хотел бы сделать так:

```
String sql = "SELECT post_date, post_title, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = post ORDER BY DESC";
```

То есть, я хочу вывести посты с post_type post, но почему-то не получается :( В чем может быть причина, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Полный код программы:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    // JDBC URL, username and password of MySQL server
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbwp";
    private static final String user = "user";
    private static final String password = "pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        try{
            //Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // Extract records without any condition.
            System.out.println("Fetching records without condition...");
            String sql = "SELECT post_date, post_title, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = post ORDER BY DESC";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                //Retrieve by column name
                String post_date  = rs.getString("post_date");
                String post_title  = rs.getString("post_title");
                String post_link = rs.getString("guid");

                //Display values
                System.out.println("Дата публикации: " + post_date);
                System.out.println("Заголовок: " + post_title);
                System.out.println("Ссылка: " + post_link);
                System.out.println("");
            }
            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: дайте больше информации. что именно вы получаете? покажите код который выполняет этот запрос.

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Если пробрасывается `SQLException` (например, потому что в вашем запросе есть ошибка), то так и нужно говорить, а также прикладывать к вопросу stacktrace.

Comment: Да, выдает такое: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC'

Comment: И еще такая ошибка: Unknown column 'post' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC

Эта ошибка связана с тем, что `ORDER BY DESC` не является корректной записью. В `ORDER BY` нужно указывать (как правило) имя столбца, по которому будет происходить сортировка. Например, `ORDER BY post_date DESC`.

> Unknown column 'post' in 'where clause'

Говорит о том, что в таблице *wp_posts* нет столбца *post* - соответственно, в `WHERE` столбец с таким названием участвовать не должен. Если предполагалось что значение *post_type* должно равняться строке "post", то нужно было сделать так: `post_type = 'post'`.